# What happened in the game Draskovic - Sutovsky (EICC 2015)?

Tags: tournament

In the European Individual Championship, the game Draskovic-Sutovsky is exhibited as
 a win for white although the end position is totally drawn.

It is also hard to imagine that black lost on time in such an easy position getting
 30 seconds at each move.

So what happened in this game? Is the result correct or should it be a draw?

```
[Event "16th European Individual Championship"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "2015.03.08"]
[Round "?"]
[White "Draskovic, Luka"]
[Black "Sutovsky, Emil"]
[Result "*"]
[WhiteElo "2432"]
[BlackElo "2626"]
[ECO "B17"]
[fen ""]

1.e4 c6 2.d4 d5 3.Nc3 dxe4 4.Nxe4 Nd7 5.Bc4 Ngf6 6.Ng5 e6 7.Qe2 Nb6 8.Bd3 
h6 9.N5f3 c5 10.dxc5 Bxc5 11.Ne5 Nbd7 12.Ngf3 Qc7 13.Bf4 Bb4+ 14.Kf1 Bd6 
15.Ng6 Bxf4 16.Nxh8 Nc5 17.Bb5+ Kf8 18.g3 Bd6 19.Kg2 b6 20.Rhe1 Bb7 21.a4 
Nce4 22.Ba6 Rc8 23.Bxb7 Qxb7 24.Rad1 Bc5 25.Nxf7 Kxf7 26.Ne5+ Kg8 27.f3 
Nf2 28.Rd2 Re8 29.Qc4 Nd5 30.Rxf2 Bxf2 31.Kxf2 Rc8 32.Qe4 b5 33.a5 Qc7 34.
Nd3 Re8 35.c3 Qxa5 36.Qd4 Rd8 37.Rxe6 Nf6 38.Rd6 Re8 39.g4 Qa1 40.Rd8 Rxd8
41.Qxd8+ Kh7 42.Qd4 a5 43.h4 Qd1 44.g5 Qd2+ 45.Kf1 hxg5 46.hxg5 Qxg5 47.
Nf4 Kh6 48.Qd2 a4 49.Qe3 Kh7 50.Kf2 Qh4+ 51.Kg2 Qg5+ 52.Kf2 Kh8 53.Qd4 Qf5
54.Qd8+ Ng8 55.Qh4+ Nh6 56.Qd8+ Kh7 57.Qd3 g5 58.Qxf5+ Nxf5 59.Ne6 Kg6 60.
Nf8+ Kh5 61.Ne6 Kh4 62.Ke2 Nd6 63.Nd4 Kg3 64.Ne6 Kh4 65.Nd4 Nc4 66.Nxb5 
Kg3 67.Na3 Ne5 68.c4 Nxf3 69.c5 g4 70.Nb5 Ne5 71.Na7 Ng6 72.c6 Nf4+ 73.Kd2
Nd5 74.Nb5 Kh2 75.c7 Nxc7 76.Nxc7 g3 77.Ne6 g2 78.Nd4 Kg3 79.Ne2+ Kf3 80.
Kd3 Kf2 81.Nf4 g1=N 82.Kc3 Ke3 83.Nd5+ Ke4 84.Nb6 Nf3 85.Nxa4 Kd5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[chess-results.com](http://www.chess-results.com/tnr157274.aspx?lan=1&art=9&fed=ISR&turdet=YES&flag=30&wi=984&snr=45) says the result was a draw. I wonder if it was one of those DGT errors where an incorrect result is reported due to the position of the kings.

Comment: +1 Indeed, after a draw kings are put to e4 and e5, and after a white win kings are put to e4 and d5. I guess the players first moved the white king to e4 and then the black king to e5, but the board registered the result too early.

Comment: This would be a logical explanation. I wonder why the result is not entered manually.